# Redirecting std::fstream to output to std::cout stream

Tags: c++, std

How to redirect std::fstream object to output to standart output stream? So I could use my object instead of std::cout.

Comment: `app.exe > file.txt`?

Comment: No, I mean output to standard output not by using std::cout object. Like myObj << "Message" would output to the same stream as cout << "Message".

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Please show a [mre] of what you are trying to do

Comment: You cannot redirect stream objects. You can (sometimes, on some operating systems) create a `fstream` object that outputs to the same (pseudo)file as the output stream. But why would you need that? `std::ostream& myObj = std::cout;` would work just fine.

Comment: I am writing a class ColoredStream, that will be able to output some colored text into some stream. I would like to use only std::fstream object to accomplish that task , so that I will be able to change output stream on the fly. Of course, I could just use std::cout object, but that would pollute the code.

Comment: `std::ostream& myObj = someCondition ? std::cout : myFileObj;` What's the problem?

Comment: I pass in stream objects where I need them.  My foo class has member function `void Print(std::ostream& out) const { out << x << ", " << y; }`  So when I want to print to a ColoredStream I call `foo.Print(coloredStream);` and when I want to print to standard out I call `foo.Print(std::cout);`.  A [mcve] of your problem would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.std::ios::rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf())` would make `fs` use the same underlying stream buffer as `std::cout`.

I wouldn't recommend it, though.